# Excel 2010 Pivot Table Filter - How to print multiple filter selection values

Tags: excel, pivot, olap

Assume we have a country dimension which I use as an filter in Excel Pivot Table, datasource is a OLAP Cube.

Now we choose some countries, the filter cell in excel is now named "(Multiple Items)" or a like, but I would like to print out / show the country names instead.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks