# Pivot Table: Showing value of (Multiple Items)

Tags: vba, excel, charts, pivot-table

I am attempting to create a pivot table and pivot chart with a title and legend that will change based on the chosen selection. For example, if I have Apple and Banana as choices, if I choose Apple the title and legend should read Apple. This part was relatively easy, however, if I choose both Apple and Banana, the pivot table shows (Multiple Items) instead.
[image: Apples and Bananas]

I would like this to instead show something like "Apple, Banana", but I haven't the slightest clue of how I can do this. I have looked around online and the few people I have found that share my issue end up not getting a response (i.e. [Excel 2010 Pivot Table Filter - How to print multiple filter selection values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592830/excel-2010-pivot-table-filter-how-to-print-multiple-filter-selection-values))

Any help with this is very much appreciated!

EDIT: I'm willing to use a macro to get this to work, so let's see if the VBA community has any ideas.

Comment: I am sorry to say that but your question is not about programming defined in the help-centre therefore its off-topic for here. You may want to try [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) instead.

Comment: @mehow it most certainly **IS** a VBA question!

Comment: Why is there an excel tag if excel questions are not permitted (seeing as how the only programming in excel is VBA and there's a tag for that)? You're right, me how, it is a problem I would like solved with no attempt, but that's because I literally have not a clue where to start. Nor could I find a place on the internet of where to start. So instead of downvoting and throwing around negativity, why not point out a place to start, or simply say you're also unsure?

Comment: @LiamBee: "Is VBA a programming language?" is certainly also a VBA question, but still off-topic. BTW: [This question is mentioned on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it)

Comment: I agree with me how. As asked this is a SuperUser question, now it is tagged `VBA` it is clearer you are open to a code solution, but your question shows no evidence of any prior coding effort on your behalf. If you have tried code, pls show your efforts.

Comment: Then again, in that meta, they say it is a "give me teh codez" question, when in reality I was more so asking for a start. Unfortunately people don't understand that when someone says "I haven't the slightest clue of how I can do this. I have looked around online and the few people I have found that share my issue end up not getting a response" that doesn't click to them "Oh, they tried." Instead it clicks to them "Oh, they want free code". VBA coding of all things too..

Comment: @Agony unfortunately you are not making any effort to understand how this site works. By assuming it's OK to ask such question you are wrong to start off with. I suggest you have a read [how to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Rubber Duck Problem](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/). Also see [no. 3 in the what's on topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: If asking for a starting place is ranked as a "give me teh codez" question as you so gracefully put then I quite frankly don't want to understand how this site "works". You've made it perfectly clear that this site is not a helpful tool for beginners, so no worries, you won't need to worry about this any longer. I won't be back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Sub test()


Dim PVI As PivotItem
Dim Pname(100) As String
Dim MS As String


For Each PVI In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("Name").PivotItems

Pname(i) = PVI.Value

If MS = "" Then

MS = Pname(i)

Else

MS = MS & ", " & Pname(i)

End If

i = i + 1
Next PVI

'MsgBox MS

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart. _
ChartTitle.Characters.Text = MS

End Sub
```

This code will cycle through the field name (in this case "Name") in the pivot table (in this case "PivotTable6") and will collect all of the data in the array `Pname`. It will then change your chart title to that array as a whole string with commas between.

May need a little tweaking for you application, but Im sure you can figure it out

Comment: Great macro and thought, but it grabs all possible choices, whether they are selected or not :( I may be able to find something to get around this though. Thank you for the start!

Comment: @Agony Hence why i said I'm sure you can figure it out ;) I'll see if I can add a filter in, but I'll be away from the comp for the rest of the evening. If you find the method, post it as an answer!

Comment: Not a problem, I will be as well, but I will definitely be looking into this. Hopefully I can find something along the `.Visible = True` lines, but this was an awesome help. If I find something, I will be sure to post as an answer :) Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Not a programming answer, but I think this does what you want.  In my example I used a table with monthly sales figures for three types of fruit: apples, bananas, and oranges. From the ribbons select Insert > Pivot Table > Pivot Chart. It should look like this:

[image: Pivot Chart placeholders]

Click on the Pivot table placeholder (on the left in my picture) and the pivot field "play area" on the right should change to include row and column labels.  Drag the item type you want on the legend in to Column Labels, drag the x-axis item to Row Labels and drag the data to be charted to Values.  Change the chart type to a line graph and you should get something like this and the filter you want is directly above the legend:

[image]

Hope this does what you wanted!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but not quite. In the table I'm using, Apples and Oranges are the same line, and that line shifts based on if you have Apples and Oranges, or just Apples selected. I want the title to change based on this, not the legend (that's a whole separate battle).

Answer (score 0):

The macro below loops through the pivot table's PageField to find the visible elements, creates a string with those elements, then updates the chart title:

```
Sub UpdateChartTitle()

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim co As ChartObject
Dim c As Chart
Dim s As String


   s = ""

   Set pt = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1) 'specify the correct PivotTable
   Set pf = pt.PageFields.Item(1) 'should be the only PageField

   For Each pi In pf.PivotItems 'loop through the fields and find only the visible ones
      If pi.Visible Then s = s & pi.Name & ", "
   Next

   s = Left(s, Len(s) - 2)

   Set co = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1) 'specify the correct chart object
   co.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = s 'change the title

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to change the title bar, place it as is under a worksheet module (to make it be triggered upon any change). Only thing you have to do is change the pointers to point to your own table and chart -

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim a As PivotField
Dim b As PivotItem
Dim c As ChartObject
Dim headerText As String

'set pointers to the objects, replace the pointers with our own !!!!!
Set a = Application.Worksheet("Sheet 1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Type")
Set c = Application.Worksheet("Sheet 1").ChartObjects("Chart 1")

'loop trough the field items and save the visible values to a string. 
'You could hone the code to change the separator for the items for it to appear the way you like. 
'Also note that the title bar on the chart has to be visible in order for this to work, 
'if not it will give you subscript out of range error.
For Each b In a.PivotItems
If b.Visible = True Then
    headerText = headerText + b.Value + ", "
End If
Next

'Set the value to the title bar
c.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = headerText
End Sub
```

Ask if you need any detailed explanations or instructions to some part of the code.